# Merging data frames and combining columns into one

Tags: r

I've got the following three dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name=c("John", "Anne", "Christine", "Andy"),
                  age=c(31, 26, 54, 48),
                  height=c(180, 175, 160, 168),
                  group=c("Student",3,5,"Employer"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(name=c("Anne", "Christine"),
                  age=c(26, 54),
                  height=c(175, 160),
                  group=c(3,5),
                  group2=c("Teacher",6), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(name=c("Christine"),
                  age=c(54),
                  height=c(160),
                  group=c(5),
                  group2=c(6),
                  group3=c("Scientist"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I'd like to combine them so that I get the following result:

```
df.all <- data.frame(name=c("John", "Anne", "Christine", "Andy"),
                     age=c(31, 26, 54, 48),
                     height=c(180, 175, 160, 168),
                     group=c("Student", "Teacher", "Scientist", "Employer"))
```

At the moment I'm doing it this way:

```
df.all <- merge(merge(df1[,c(1,4)], df2[,c(1,5)], all=TRUE, by="name"),
                df3[,c(1,6)], all=TRUE, by="name")
row.ind <- which(df.all$group %in% c(6,5))
df.all[row.ind, c("group")] <- df.all[row.ind, c("group2")]
row.ind2 <- which(df.all$group2 %in% c(6))
df.all[row.ind2, c("group")] <- df.all[row.ind2, c("group3")]
```

This isn't generalisable and it is really messy. Maybe there would be a way to use `merge_all` or `merge_recurse` for the merging step (especially as there might be more than two dataframes to be merged), but I haven't figured out how. These two don't produce the right result:

```
df.all <- merge_all(list(df1, df2, df3))
df.all <- merge_recurse(list(df1, df2, df3), by=c("name"))
```

Is there a more general and elegant way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another possible approach, if I understand what you're ultimately after. (It is not clear what the numeric values in the "group" columns are, so I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for.)

Use `Reduce()` to merge your multiple `data.frame`s.

```
temp <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(df1, df2, df3))
names(temp)[4] <- "group1" # Rename "group" to "group1" for reshaping 
temp
#        name age height   group1  group2    group3
# 1      Andy  48    168 Employer    <NA>      <NA>
# 2      Anne  26    175        3 Teacher      <NA>
# 3 Christine  54    160        5       6 Scientist
# 4      John  31    180  Student    <NA>      <NA>
```

Use `reshape()` to reshape your data from wide to long.

```
df.all <- reshape(temp, direction = "long", idvar="name", varying=4:6, sep="")
df.all
#                  name age height time     group
# Andy.1           Andy  48    168    1  Employer
# Anne.1           Anne  26    175    1         3
# Christine.1 Christine  54    160    1         5
# John.1           John  31    180    1   Student
# Andy.2           Andy  48    168    2      <NA>
# Anne.2           Anne  26    175    2   Teacher
# Christine.2 Christine  54    160    2         6
# John.2           John  31    180    2      <NA>
# Andy.3           Andy  48    168    3      <NA>
# Anne.3           Anne  26    175    3      <NA>
# Christine.3 Christine  54    160    3 Scientist
# John.3           John  31    180    3      <NA>
```

Take advantage of the fact that `as.numeric()` will coerce characters to `NA`, and use `na.omit()` to remove all of the rows with `NA` values.

```
na.omit(df.all[is.na(as.numeric(df.all$group)), ])
#                  name age height time     group
# Andy.1           Andy  48    168    1  Employer
# John.1           John  31    180    1   Student
# Anne.2           Anne  26    175    2   Teacher
# Christine.3 Christine  54    160    3 Scientist
```

Again, this might be over-generalizing your problem--there might be NA values in other columns, for example--but it might help direct you towards a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I got used to the `reshape` package so much that I'm actually surprised about what you can achieve with base `R`.   Also thanks for the explanation of the `as.numeric()` part.

Answer (score 4):

First step is to use `merge_recurse` with `all.x = TRUE`:

```
library(reshape)
merge.all <- merge_recurse(list(df1, df2, df3), all.x = TRUE)
#        name age height    group  group2    group3
# 1      Anne  26    175        3 Teacher      <NA>
# 2 Christine  54    160        5       6 Scientist
# 3      John  31    180  Student    <NA>      <NA>
# 4      Andy  48    168 Employer    <NA>      <NA>
```

Then you can use `apply` to get the last non-`NA` group from all the "group" columns:

```
group.cols <- grep("group", colnames(merge.all))
merge.all <- data.frame(merge.all[-group.cols],
                        group = apply(merge.all[group.cols], 1,
                                      function(x)tail(na.omit(x), 1)))
#        name age height     group
# 1      Anne  26    175   Teacher
# 2 Christine  54    160 Scientist
# 3      John  31    180   Student
# 4      Andy  48    168  Employer
```

Comment: I like your `tail` step here. I would prefer using `Reduce` though (as in my answer) to having to load a package just to do the merging.

Comment: Great, thanks! I really like the approach to use `tail`, and thanks for showing how to use `merge_recurse` in the right way.

Comment: A bug in `merge_recurse` has the effect of ignoring all arguments after the first except, in the trivial case of merging just two data frames.   So your example happens to work fine without the `all.x = TRUE` parameter.